# Value not changing when passing by reference

Tags: c++, matrix

```
class Matrix {
    private:
        double data[rows*columns];
    public:
        Matrix(Vector&, Vector&);
        void add(const Matrix&);
        void mult(double);
        double trace();
        double norm();
        void print();
};



void Matrix::print() {
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint|ios::fixed);
    cout.precision(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << data[i * rows + j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        }
  }

void Matrix::add(const Matrix &m){
    for(int i=0;i<rows*columns;i++){
            data[i]+=m.data[i];

    }

}

menu () {
//...
   else if (choice==3){
        cout<<"A+B="<<endl;
        Matrix A(a,b);
        Matrix B(c,d);
        A.add(B);
        A.print();


    }
}
```

I am working on a project that takes in values for for vectors and creates two matrices. The provide code is adding two matrices. When the matrices are  added and A is printed, the value of Matrix A is not updated. When the choice to print Matrix A is chosen again the first value of the matrix is outputted. The code I have correctly creates matrices and b, prints them out exactly as I want, and adds them together. However, as I said, the add function does not change matrix A, even though I called by reference. Also, I cannot change method parameters, as I have an instructor that is forcing us to do projects one specific way (ridiculous, I know).

Edit. I added in class definition.

Comment: have you tried debugging (setting a breakpoint to add)? Additionally, it would be helpful if you present a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (http://www.sscce.org/) that shows the problem. Your code here is missing at least the Matrix type definition.

Comment: The Add function looks fine. Can you maybe show Matrix header file? and Ctor that is used above? Since you define both Matrices immediately before adding them I'd be interested to understand what they are initialized with.

Comment: Nothing in what you've shown is a problem. All we can say at this point is to print out `A` and `B` before and after the add. Another possibility is that either `rows` or `columns` is zero.

Comment: A.print() correctly gives the correct values of matrix a + matrix b. However, once 'choice 3' exits, and I try and print matrix a again, it reverts back to it's originally inputted values

Comment: That's because it's local to that `if` block.

Comment: I'm passing by reference so why would it not update.  Also when Matrix A and Matrix B are not declared in the block it outputs zeroes.

Comment: You're only passing the input matrix by reference. It really doesn't matter. `A` is the object being changed, not `m`.

Comment: How could I update that object then using similar syntax?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `A` or `B` to be visible outside of that `if` block, you'll have to declare them with greater scope. If you already have them declared at a greater scope then you are shadowing those names in the `if` block and using a local object that will disappear after the block, leaving the outer object unchanged.